# Creating 4D arrays from 3D arrays in Python

Tags: python, arrays

I'm having trouble getting a series of 3D "images" stored as a single 4D array. The code below is what I'm using to convert the 2D 640x512 images from the camera into a 3D array.

```
listImage = []

for i in range(492):
    fname = '2019-12-04_11-59-12' + str(i) + '.fits'
    fits_import = FITS.Read('Run 4\\' + fname)
    listImage.append(fits_import[1])

arrayListImage = np.asarray(listImage)
```

The result, "arrayListImage", has a shape of [492, 640, 512].  Using the same code to read in 2 3D arrays results in an array of shape (2,). The type of "fits_import[1]" is a numpy.ndarray.

I  expected this to return an array of shape [2, 492, 640, 512]. Why is this method not consistent in going to 4D?

Answer (score 0):

Use `np.stack` instead of `np.asarray`:

```
arrayListImage = np.stack(listImage, axis=0)
```